# How can I click this button?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, message

The element isn't being recognized, I'm trying to click the button after I put in a file submission. I tried having the keyboard press enter as an alternate solution but it doesn't work.

[Image of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojuMa.png)

```
def ClickButton():
action = ActionChains(web)
button_path = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[local-name()='svg' and @data-qa='send-message']/*[localname()='path']")))

 # click the item
action.move_to_element(button_path)
action.click(on_element=button_path)
# perform the operation
action.perform()
```

Comment: can you confirm the page url?

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('svg[size="24"] \
[data-qa="send-message"] \
[data-button-disabled="false"]')
button.click()
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I tried the code "AttributeError: type object 'By' has no attribute 'CSS'" I tried switching it to CSS_SELECTOR but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: @DavidHuynh I have update my answer. Make sure to have a reference to the Selenium driver